# Facebook link posting through Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post link using Graph API. I am posting to https://graph.facebook.com/me/links. It is working as shown below. I want to do it similar to how Snip.it displays. I mean show "via Snip.it" in the bottom as shown in the figure below. If I keep the cursor on top of the link, a hover panel is also displayed.

Is it possible to do like that via Graph API? If not, how is Snip.it doing it?

By the way, If I post a link to feed url (https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed), I get the error "The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL.".

Through my app:

[image]

Through Snip.it:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use feed dialog mentioned in following link [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). "snip it" is a Facebook app, in feed dialog you specify the app_id, by defining app_id Facebook will add "via" + "your app name" in each feed dialog.

Comment: I've tried to add app_id to the api call (in my case /[page_id]/feed), but there's no way "via my_app_name" is going to appear..!
Is there something I have to edit in my app settings?